# Using karate framework and javascript the scenario is looping continuously

Tags: javascript, karate

Using karate framework i am invoking the pooling js function as below. Its repeating the scenario even after the actual status moved to complete. I want to know how to stop the loop and no need to call the scenario again once actual status is complete

```
  """
  function(status) {
    var actualstatus = null
    while (actualstatus != 'Complete') {
      var packageId = {"packageid": packageid}; 
      var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature',packageId); 
      var greeting = result.response;

      if(greeting.payload.progressStatus == status) 
        { actualstatus = greeting.payload.progressStatus
         return;} 
      actualstatus = greeting.payload.progressStatus
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); 
    }
  }
  """
```

Scenario: one

```
* def packageId = packageid
* def result = call read('Progress.feature') {packageid: '#(packageId)'}
* def current = result.response
* def status = 'Complete'
* call waitUntil status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your JS, please take the help of someone near you if possible.

Here's my attempt since I can't replicate your environment fully. Keep it simple. Also you can add logic to exit the loop if it carries on for too long etc.

```
"""
  function(status, id) {
    while (true) {
      var jsonArg = { packageid: id }; 
      var result = karate.call('extractProgress.feature', jsonArg); 
      var response = result.response;
      if (response.myPath == status) {
        return;
      }
      java.lang.Thread.sleep(100); 
    }
  }
"""
```

Comment: i tried that option still its looping the scenario even after the condition is false

Comment: @user1980552 the time has come for me to point you to this page. all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue